# TYPO3 Route Enhancers: converting 'routeFieldName' to lowercase?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Intro: In TYPO3 v9 you're able to set up speaking URLs out-of-the-box without using the RealURL extension. This feature is configured with YAML in a so-called *Site Configuration*.

The following configuration excerpt extends the speaking URLs for the popular news extension. Below config `category_name` and `tag_name` I select the title field in the corresponding database tables.

**Q: Is it possible to convert these titles to lowercase letters?** The current configuration results in URLs like *domain.com/category/TYPO3*.

```
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [17,4]
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      # Detail view:
      - routePath: '/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments: {'news_title': 'news'}
      # Categories:
      - routePath: '/{category_name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments: {'category_name': 'overwriteDemand/categories'}
      # Tags:
      - routePath: '/{tag_name}'
        _controller: 'News::list'
        _arguments: {'tag_name': 'overwriteDemand/tags'}
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
      category_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
      tag_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_tag'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy. You can do it as made it in the [ext: news](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php)

I did it the same for category and tag and it is all working good.

[image]

Look at attachment:
[More about it here](https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/795)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid extending the database with extra *path segment* fields for every record, by converting the title fields. As this currently seems not feasible, your solution is the right choice. Thanks!